# Devices cannot see each others' network shares

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-xp, wireless-networking, setup

I am trying to form a home network.  I have:

- DSL
- Two Wi-Fi access points
- 5 main devices

My wife uses an XP in the home office where the DSL router is connected to the first AP. I have an iMac and there is a printer. All 3 connect wirelessly.

A cable runs from the router to the second AP where the kids have a Windows 7 device. We can all print to the printer. Everybody is on the same 192.168. network and can use the internet. The DSL router uses the pace.com domain and all the users have the same workgroup name.

But file sharing and seeing each other as members of a network has proved confusing. And I cannot see the forest for the trees.

Everybody seems to ping everybody else OK (except no one can ping the Win 7 box which can ping the others). DNS on the LAN works correctly. Nobody sees any shares except their own.

Where should I go next troubleshooting?

Comment: What model devices are you using (WIFI access points)?

Comment: The pinging is likely a routing issue.  The network shares depending on your routing you should be able to access manually (using the IP of device) only in an outward direction (from inner most network accessing a network further out).  Out being closest to the internet connection.

Comment: Also, I would note... it is entirely possible that you can't fix the routing issue without different routing hardware.

Comment: A decent AP ought to be able to allow traversal if both are plugged directly to the router, not daisy-chained, & also if both are actually set to AP mode, therefore not attempting to do their own DHCP or NAT. I have a similar [working] setup though I link everything by a switch before the router, so that might be the difference.

Comment: Actually thinking about it, you could connect to the switch port side on the second AP instead of the WAN side.  Then disable DHCP on the second AP and it should work.  This all depends on what the actual equipment is though I guess.  Still need a comment on that or question edit with model of the wireless APs.

Comment: I believe that I have 'router2' connected to 'router1' at its network port and not into one of the lan ports. I will investigate when I get home this afternoon.  modem router is pace att 5031nv & AP1 is ASUS RT-AC68U & AP2 is Amped AP300 connected via ethernet in its network port. I believe only the pace is doing routing/dns/dhcp and the others are in AP mode. I will also verify that.

Comment: @eddacker Based on your comment and the setup guide I found for the Amped AP300 my original assessment seems correct.  Each device is a router and each device connected behind router 1 or router 2 are using PAT (NAT Overload).  I will repost an answer for you shortly.

Comment: @eddacker Also, a note so you are aware.  All 3 of the devices do routing (each one is used as a gateway).  None of the devices do DNS (each setting gets passed down via DHCP and your ISPs DNS is used).  All 3 of those devices do DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

Internet|---|RT-AC68U|---|Subnet A|---|AP300|---|Subnet B

1. First access the Amped AP300 Setup page.
   a.  Connect to Subnet B via WIFI
   b.  Open a web browser and navigate to: `http://192.168.1.240/`
2. Go to More Settings -> IP Settings
3. Set DHCP to disabled.
4. Click Apply.
5. Disconnect cable connected to the "Network" port of the AP300.
6. Connect the cable which was disconnected in step 5 to a "Wired Devices" port of the AP300.

Comment: I strongly feel that the above answer is a path toward the solution and not an answer by itself - please comment to request information and post your answer. Appreciate your explanation

Comment: @eddacker Any luck?